# Como converter o formato de um vetor Date sem ele mudar para character?

Tags: r

Estou começando agora no R e apanhando muito com a classe Date.
Quero mudar o formato "%Y-%m-%d" para "%b-%Y", porém ele muda também a classe do vetor.

```
x.data1 <- as.Date(c("2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01",
            "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01",
            "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01"),
            format = "%Y-%m-%d")

x.data <- format.Date(x.data1, format = "%b/%Y")
```

Preciso colocar este vetor como eixo x em plot (ggplot), mas a função scale_x_continuous() não é aplicável a classe character.

adendo: ja tentei usar o lubridate e ja li várias outras perguntas aqui e em outras fontes... mas nada funciona :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário converter o formato antes de traçar o gráfico, o pacote `ggplot2` reconhece objetos de classe `"Date"` e usando os argumentos `date_breaks` e `date_labels` de `scale_x_date` obtém-se o formato que se pretende.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(x.data1, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b/%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados**

```
x.data1 <- as.Date(c("2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01",
                     "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01",
                     "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01", "2017-07-01"),
                   format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dados <- data.frame(x.data1, y = seq_along(x.data1))
```